# how to repopulate set of html on button click

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel

In my laravel project there is a blade file for adding a shop with owner details. i need to add a button "Add another shop" so that, on clicking it the same set of html table need to be appeared. I'm a newbie in laravel framework. so please correct me if any mistakes occurred in my code below.

My add.blade.php

```
$data = /* get shop details from db */
Name: <input type="text" name="name" id="name" value="$data['shop_name']"/>
Location:  <select name='shop_location' class='shop_location'>
   <option value="0">Select</option>
   <?php   
      $idl=Location::get();
     $location_id_drop_down='';
     if($data['shop_city_id'])
     $loc=$data['shop_city_id'];
     else 
     $loc=Input::old('shop_location');
      foreach($idl as $lrow)
     {
      if($loc==$lrow->location_id)
     {
     $location_id_drop_down.="<option value='" . $lrow->location_id . "' selected='selected'>" . $lrow->location_name . "</option>";
    }
   else
   {
    $location_id_drop_down.="<option value='" . $lrow->location_id . "'>" . $lrow->location_name . "</option>";
   }
  }                                                                   
  echo $location_id_drop_down;
  ?>
 </select>
 State: <input type="text" name="state" id="state" value="$data['shop_state']"/>
 <?php echo Form::button("Add another shop",array('id'=>'extra','onclick'=>'extraaa()')); ?> 

<div id="extra_div" style="display: none;"</div>
```

Script function

```
function extraaa() {
    var e=1;
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "<?php echo URL::to('admin');?>/extrashop",
        data: {}
    })
    .done(function(data) {
       $("#extra_div").html(data);
            $("#extra_div").css("display","block");
    });
    e++;
}
```

`AdminController` extra shop function

```
public function anyExtraShop($id){
    return View::make('shop.admin_extra_shop');
}
```

In the admin_extra_shop.blade.php i wrote the html table containing shop name , location,state etc. but this only adds one extra shop. i need to add more shops as per the admin needs.

Did anyone knows how to solve this issue??

**EDIT**

Some edition is made on the java script code and controller function which i got now.

Comment: were you able to solve your problem?.

Comment: yeah i solved my problem by returning a view blade that contains the html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Laravel requires you to return something from the controller method. Instead of  echo $id; exit(); use Laravel json response.

```
return Response::json(array('id' => $id);
```

Also you might wanna call $this->layout = null; before calling this if your controller is extending BaseController

to get the html template as the ajax response use

```
return Response::json(array('id' => $id, 'data' => View::make('shop.admin_extra_shop'));
```

but instead of reloading the whole view via ajax what i would do is return just one item (shop) from the controller and append it to the list with jquery or so.

Comment: Hi, i've edited my post. can you please check it and help me??

Comment: is the 500 error gone now ? and you should be getting a json response ?

Comment: yes.. 500 error gone and now i get the html in the "extradiv" section. but its html elements ids are same. i need to identify them uniquely and also at present only one extra new shop is adding to the div.i need to add as many as the admin clicks the button. hope you understood what i meant.